# not understanding regexp_like in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

I have define for example below in my With clause in query:

`'.+d\$'` as `sec_level_pattern` from dual

And now i can see below condition in select query:

```
not regexp_like(name,sec_level_pattern)
```

`name` is column from my `rd_tst` table.

What does the condition `regexp_like` checks here ? I have seen few question about `regexp_like` but did not understand what actually will check in my use case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what did i need to change for `sec_level_pattern` to return all the name ?

Your sample data seems to have the format:

- Start of the string;
- Two upper-case alphabetic characters;
- Ten upper-case alpha-numeric characters;
- The characters `.GTX`; then
- The end of the string.

You want a regular expression that matches the same things such as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( names, '^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{10}\.GTX$' );
```

Which for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Names ) AS
SELECT 'AT0000730007.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CH0012032048.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DE0005550602.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DE0007236101.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DE000A1EWWW0.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DE000ENAG999.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DE000TUAG000.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FI0009000681.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FR0000120172.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FR0000125007.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'IT0003132476.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NL0000235190.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NL0011794037.GTX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SE0000148884.GTX' FROM DUAL;
```

Returns all the names:

> ```
> | NAMES            |
> | :--------------- |
> | AT0000730007.GTX |
> | CH0012032048.GTX |
> | DE0005550602.GTX |
> | DE0007236101.GTX |
> | DE000A1EWWW0.GTX |
> | DE000ENAG999.GTX |
> | DE000TUAG000.GTX |
> | FI0009000681.GTX |
> | FR0000120172.GTX |
> | FR0000125007.GTX |
> | IT0003132476.GTX |
> | NL0000235190.GTX |
> | NL0011794037.GTX |
> | SE0000148884.GTX |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7327157b37a0a4a70992933e1c29017c)*

Answer (score 1):

This pattern:

```
'.+d\$'
```

is really strings.  It is looking for at least one character (non-newline generally) followed by the lowercase `'d'` and then by the literal `'$'`.  So, this matches:

```
Xd$
123d$abc
```

It is equivalent to:  `like '%_d$%'`.

In all likelihood, you intend the much more reasonable `'\d+$'`.  This would match any string that ends in a digit.

Comment: i have just edited question and still have confusion as my query returns only DE000A1EWWW0.GTX...what did i need to change for  sec_level_pattern to return all the name ?